# Count all users having specific amount sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database table similar to the one below.

```
id     user_id     amount    
1      5546        1000
2      5546        52
3      53          10000
4      45          120
5      5546        10
```

Each user's payment is recorded there, which means each user can have multiple records.

Now I need to get number of users having more than 10$ sum of amounts.

Here is some basic code I wrote but it gives me many results instead of one counted number but I dont understand why.

I mean, its probably because I am grouping by but I need to count it by user id so no idea how to make it properly.

```
SELECT count(*), sum(amount) as amount FROM `revenues` 

GROUP BY user_id

HAVING amount > 10
```

This question might seem stupid but please tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT sum(amount) as amount
      FROM `revenues` 
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING sum(amount) > 10
     ) r;
```

Notice that I repeated the expression.  You have aliased the `sum()` with the same name as the column.  I can never remember if `having` in MySQL refers to the column or the alias.  So, the query repeats the expression just to avoid potential problems.

Comment: MySQL allows the use of aliases in `group by` and `having` clauses, see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-alias/#3

Comment: @TheWildHealer . . . It is not whether or not they are allowed.  It is about the scoping rules.  Which comes first, the alias definition or a table definition?